How to fix Apache PHP rejecting post requests which are over 40MBs
My php Laravel API when put behind apache2 (with ssl) when making a post request which is roughly 40Mbs in size, it gives a 500 internal error with following log
[Wed Jul 10 21:08:51.397912 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3176136] [client X.X.X.X:57229] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Request Startup: POST Content-Length of 72701360 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes

but when using php artisan serve command, when accessing my endpoint, it works without an issue. trying to figure out where to increase the limit
php.ini (used by all)
/etc/php/8.3/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php/8.3/cli/php.ini and /etc/php/8.3/fpm/php.ini are identical
[PHP]
upload_max_filesize = 2028M
post_max_size = 2048M
memory_limit = 2048M
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = -1
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
zend.exception_ignore_args = On
zend.exception_string_param_max_len = 0
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 900
max_input_time = 900
max_input_vars = 3000
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 2G
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2G
max_file_uploads = 2000
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=openssl
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
extension=sockets
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
[filter]
[iconv]
[imap]
[intl]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[Phar]
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 
mail.add_x_header = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.cookie_samesite =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.sid_length = 26
session.trans_sid_tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="
session.sid_bits_per_character = 5
[Assertion]
zend.assertions = -1
[COM]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[dba]
[opcache]
[curl]
[openssl]
[ffi]

my .htaccess is
php_value upload_max_filesize 2048M
php_value post_max_size 2048M
php_value max_execution_time 360000
php_value max_input_time 360000
php_value memory_limit 2048M
LimitRequestBody 0

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    
    # Disable if using build in cors
    # Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>


Create a file that contains only <?php>phpinfo(); and browse to it. That will show you (among tons of other things) what the actual value for upload_max_filesize is, and should tell you what config file(s) are being checked, and in what order, to come up with that number.

You might want to also check Apache's limit.
See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686288/apaches-limit-to-post-request-size

After printing out phpinfo() I noticed that the values wheren't changed.
Simply had to update php.ini (all 3 versons) and then restart the php8.3-fpm service for the changes to reflect
